# GatsbyJS and graphql - Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'mdx')

Tags: graphql, gatsby, gatsby-plugin-mdx

I have the following folder structure:

- pages

  - index.js
  - about.js
  - archive

    - index.js
    - docu-{mdx.frontmatter__key}-{mdx.frontmatter__slug}.js
    - components

      - single-docu-sections

        - overview

          - overview.js
          - index.js

in docu-{mdx.frontmatter__key}-{mdx.frontmatter__slug}.js I have the following:

```
import * as React from 'react'
import Layout from '../../components/layout/layout'
import SingleDocuLayout from './components/single-docu-layout/single-docu-layout'
import Seo from '../../components/seo'
import { graphql } from 'gatsby'
import { GatsbyImage, getImage } from 'gatsby-plugin-image'

const SingleDocu = ({ data, children }) => {
  const image = getImage(data.mdx.frontmatter.heroImage)
  return (
    <Layout pageTitle={data.mdx.frontmatter.title}>
      <p>Posted: {data.mdx.frontmatter.date}</p>
    <GatsbyImage
      image={image}
      alt={data.mdx.frontmatter.heroImageAlt}
    />
      {children}
      <SingleDocuLayout />
    </Layout>
  )
}

export const query = graphql`
  query($id: String) {
    mdx(id: {eq: $id}) {
      frontmatter {
        title
        date(formatString: "MMMM DD, YYYY")
        heroImageAlt
        heroImage {
          childImageSharp {
            gatsbyImageData
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }

export const Head = ({ data }) => <Seo title={data.mdx.frontmatter.title} />

export default SingleDocu`
```

and here I can get the data from the files.

In overview.js I have the following code:

```
import * as React from 'react'
import { useStaticQuery,graphql } from 'gatsby'
import { GatsbyImage, getImage } from 'gatsby-plugin-image'


import {
  Wrapper,
  BackgroundAsset,
  BackgroundImage, 
} from "./style";

const Overview = ({ data, children }) => {
  
  const query = useStaticQuery(graphql`
  query {
    mdx{
      frontmatter {
        title
        date(formatString: "MMMM DD, YYYY")
        heroImageAlt
        heroImage {
          childImageSharp {
            gatsbyImageData
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
`)
  const image = getImage(data.mdx.frontmatter.heroImage)
  return (
    <>
    "overview"
    </>
   /*  <Wrapper data-testid="overview">
    <BackgroundAsset>
      <BackgroundImage>
        <GatsbyImage
          //image={image}
          //alt={data.mdx.frontmatter.heroImageAlt}
        />
      </BackgroundImage>
    </BackgroundAsset>
    
  </Wrapper> */
  )
}

export default Overview
```

Trying with or without useStaticQuery I get the following error:
Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'mdx')
./src/pages/archive/components/single-docu-sections/overview/overview.js:30

28 |   }
29 | `)

> 30 |   const image = getImage(data.mdx.frontmatter.heroImage)
> |                              ^
> 31 |   return (
> 32 |     <>
> 33 |     "overview"

Can someone help me  to fix this?
Thanks

I would like to know how I can get data successfully.
I tried graphql query using useStaticQuery and without but get the same error